# (Charts by Daniel Gindi) Radar Chart - Setting Y Minimum and Maximum Values

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using this to set the maximum and minimum values of the radar chart :
`self.radarChart.yAxis.calcMinMax(min: 0.0, max: 100.0)`

It seems to be fine and dandy but, i get this result,

[image: This]

or if that doesn't work: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyP2K.jpg

The problem here is the "120" at the top which isn't supposed to be there *becasue I set the Min to 0 and the Max to 100.0*

Edit 1 :
Due to request for more code
Here is the radar chart setup code:

        `let yse1 = ys1.enumerate().map {idx, i in return ChartDataEntry(value:i,xIndex:idx)}
        let xdata = RadarChartData(xVals: xs)
        let ds1 = RadarChartDataSet(yVals: yse1, label: "Quiz Performance Data")
        ds1.colors = [color]
        ds1.fillColor = color
        ds1.drawFilledEnabled = true
        xdata.addDataSet(ds1)
        self.radarChart.data = xdata
        self.radarChart.descriptionText = "Your performance data"`

All else code in the backend and I wouldn't feel comfortable sharing the rest.
Thank you so much in advanced,

Akhil

Comment: Please kindly show us your code (not just one line).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 self.radarChart.yAxis.axisMinValue = 0.0
 self.radarChart.yAxis.axisMaxValue = 100.0
```

instead of `calcMinMax`

For Charts 3.0 use the following:

```
  self.radarChart.yAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
  self.radarChart.yAxis.axisMaximum = 100.0
```